# Keycloak / SpringBoot - The Issuer <https://example.com> provided in the OpenID Configuration did not match the requested issuer <https://bar.com>

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

I have an issue with a project I just join.

The technical stack :

- Jhipster with Angular and SpringBoot
- Keycloak

I replace the right url by example.com and bar.com

[application.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHA9h.png)

The endpoint https://bar.com/auth/realms/artemis/.well-known/openid-configuration returns this :

```
{
  "issuer": "https://example.com/auth/realms/artemis",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://example.com/auth/realms/artemis/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "https://bar.com/auth/realms/artemis/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "token_introspection_endpoint": "https://bar.com/auth/realms/artemis/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://bar.com/auth/realms/artemis/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://example.com/auth/realms/artemis/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
  "jwks_uri": "https://bar.com/auth/realms/artemis/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
  "check_session_iframe": "https://example.com/auth/realms/artemis/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
}
```

When I run the App I got this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Issuer "https://example.com/auth/realms/artemis" provided in the OpenID Configuration did not match the requested issuer "https://bar.com:8443/auth/realms/artemis"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.fromOidcIssuerLocation(ClientRegistrations.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getBuilderFromIssuerIfPossible(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistration(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.lambda$getClientRegistrations$0(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:53)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.clientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9d328e3.CGLIB$clientRegistrationRepository$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9d328e3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1d0ccf00.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9d328e3.clientRegistrationRepository(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

I'm new with Spring Boot. I don't really understand what I have to do to be able to use 2 differents url.

Thx for the help ! I can give you more informations if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `application.yaml` config `issuer-uri` is not matching `issuer` of used OIDC Keycloak realm. Set it to `https://example.com/auth/realms/artemis` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

<sub><sup>-- This may not be relative to OP's case. But for other cases.
-- Just a headsup.
-- I am not a professional on this, I could be wrong, but it helped in my case.</sup></sub>

The problem could occur from the other side, in the `Authorization Server`.

So, for example, you may not only need to look at the `application.yml` in the `Resource Server`:

```yaml
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri: http://localhost:9999
```

you may also need to look at the `Authorization Server`:

```java
  @Bean
  public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
    return new ProviderSettings().issuer("http://localhost:9999"); 
  }
```