# Issuer "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster" provided in the configuration metadata did not match the requested issuer

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, jhipster

I am trying to set up a JHipster app using KeyCloak via docker-compose.yml

On start up am getting:

> The Issuer "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster" provided in
> the configuration metadata did not match the requested issuer
> "http://keycloak:9080/auth/realms/jhipster"

As I understand it
http://keycloak:9080/auth/realms/jhipster
is correct - but where and what is "the configuration metadata"?

Explanations like this one are not specific enough for me to understand.: [Keycloak / SpringBoot - The Issuer <https://example.com> provided in the OpenID Configuration did not match the requested issuer <https://bar.com>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476429/keycloak-springboot-the-issuer-https-example-com-provided-in-the-openid)

In following the docs https://www.jhipster.tech/security/ I have set up the following

### DOCKER_COMPOSE.YML

```
  myapp:
    depends_on:
      - 'keycloak'
    image: ....
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,api-docs
      - MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=...
      - SPRING_LIQUIBASE_URL=...
      - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30 # gives time for other services to boot before the application
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER_URI=http://keycloak:9080/auth/realms/jhipster
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_ID=web_app
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=web_app
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/oidc

      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_CLIENT_ID=admin
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=admin
      
      - POSTGRES_USER=...
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=...
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
    command:
      [
        '-b',
        '0.0.0.0',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING',
        '-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000',
        '-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled'
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
      - keycloak-data:/opt/jboss
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin # "${KEYCLOAK_USER}"
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin # "${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}"
      - DB_VENDOR=h2
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:9080/auth
      
    # If you want to do not expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # add "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 10990:10990
```

### DOCKER_COMPOSE .ENV has

```
KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak/auth/realms/jhipster
```

which I have confirmed by changing is the value from the error message.

### /ETC/HOSTS FILE

In the browser http://keycloak:9080/auth/realms/jhipster gives

```
{
"realm":"jhipster",
"public_key":".....",
"token-service":"http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect",
"account-service":"http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/account",
"tokens-not-before":0}
```

which I think means the windows /etc/hosts file is correct.

## POM

In case its relevant the POM follows. Its a reasonably old version of JHipster.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>...</name>
<description>...</description>
<repositories>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-repository -->
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-plugin-repository -->
</pluginRepositories>

<!-- jhipster-needle-distribution-management -->

<properties>
    <!-- Build properties -->
    <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <node.version>v14.17.6</node.version>
    <npm.version>7.24.2</npm.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <start-class>....</start-class>
    <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m</argLine>
    <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
    <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
    <!-- These remain empty unless the corresponding profile is active -->
    <profile.no-liquibase />
    <profile.api-docs />
    <profile.tls />

    <!-- Dependency versions -->
    <jhipster-dependencies.version>7.3.0</jhipster-dependencies.version>
    <!-- The spring-boot version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
    <spring-boot.version>2.5.5</spring-boot.version>
    <!-- The hibernate version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
    <hibernate.version>5.4.32.Final</hibernate.version>
    <!-- The javassist version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/${hibernate.version} -->
    <javassist.version>3.27.0-GA</javassist.version>
    <!-- The liquibase version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
    <liquibase.version>4.5.0</liquibase.version>
    <liquibase-hibernate5.version>4.5.0</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
    <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
    <jaxb-runtime.version>2.3.3</jaxb-runtime.version>
    <archunit-junit5.version>0.21.0</archunit-junit5.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <!-- Plugin versions -->
    <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
    <maven-site-plugin.version>3.9.1</maven-site-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.3.1</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.10</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
    <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
    <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
    <maven-idea-plugin.version>2.2.1</maven-idea-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>3.3.1</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <checkstyle.version>9.0</checkstyle.version>
    <nohttp-checkstyle.version>0.0.9</nohttp-checkstyle.version>
    <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.12.0</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    <checksum-maven-plugin.version>1.11</checksum-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-antrun-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
    <git-commit-id-plugin.version>5.0.0</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
    <modernizer-maven-plugin.version>2.3.0</modernizer-maven-plugin.version>
    <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.7</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    <jib-maven-plugin.version>3.1.4</jib-maven-plugin.version>
    <jib-maven-plugin.image>eclipse-temurin:11-jre-focal</jib-maven-plugin.image>
    <jib-maven-plugin.architecture>amd64</jib-maven-plugin.architecture>
    <lifecycle-mapping.version>1.0.0</lifecycle-mapping.version>
    <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.0.0</properties-maven-plugin.version>
    <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.9.0.2155</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-property -->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
        <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <!-- Inherited version from Spring Boot can't be used because of regressions -->
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>archunit-junit5-api</artifactId>
        <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Adding the engine dependency to the surefire-plugin unfortunately does not work in the current version. -->
    <!-- https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_junit_5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>archunit-junit5-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security OAuth 2.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Cloud -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Cucumber -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.792</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.792</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Keycloak must know which URL itself is reachable on from the outside. IIRC you can configure this in your client or realm settings in keycloak (replace localhost with keycloak)

Comment: Yes, thanks Felix, that info is right and helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

```
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:9080/auth
```

You're requesting things from http://**keycloak**:9080/auth but the answers from Keycloak reference http://**localhost**:9080/auth. Spring complains about that discrepancy.

Either set `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://keycloak:9080/auth` or don't set `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` at all (Keycloak then deduces the URL from the request).